# Meta key not working in Emacs with evil mode (even in the Gui verision) (MAC)

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have started using Emacs as my editor and because I used to use vim as my editor, I decided to try Evil mode on Emacs. The problem is that if I try using the meta key (esc key) with another key (M-x as an example), the command doesn't get registered.

Launching Emacs with the -Q option makes the meta key work again, so I think is a evil mode problem.

This is my init.el file if it's necessary.

```
(tool-bar-mode 0)
(menu-bar-mode 0)
(set-scroll-bar-mode nil)
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/evil")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

I haven't changed any setting from evil and searching online I couldn't find anything to solve my problem.
Does anyone know about this problem and possibly how to fix it?

Comment: What OS do you use. If Mac add this to your init. (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)

Comment: @dunkaroo Just tried but no luck there.

Comment: That lisp code made "Option" key on Mac act as "Meta" key in Emacs. Are you on Mac? Here is a link from the Wiki https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems

Comment: @dunkaroo Oh that's what you meant now it works. But shouldn't the meta key be assigned to the esc-key?

Comment: "escape" key in Emacs is a very special key. "M-x" = Hold down Option in your case tap "x" then let go of Option key. OR tap "ESC" then tap "x"